# Video Lectures on Design and Analysis of Experiments

Tags: references, experiment-design

Where can I find video lectures or tutorials on **design and analysis of experiments**?  E.g. something similar in scope and depth to Montgomery's [Design and Analysis of Experiments](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1118146921)?

Comment: See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IEUTRhyoHNc&list=PLPjSqITyvDeWS9Lxp4jreGJ7eNsxHxJA8